# Nested object with type search using recursion

Tags: java, data-structures

I have nested objects having the same type. See below JSON format and java object structure.

```
public class Resource{
private String name
......
public List<Resource> subResources;
}



{
    "name": "root",
    "subResources": [
        {
            "name": "child1_level1",
            "subResources": [
                {
                    "name": "child1_level2",
                    "subResources": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "child2_level1",
            "subResources": [
                {
                    "name": "child2_level2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to search for objects with names at any level. I have tried with recursion but what I found is that even the object found it overridden with a null value. The reason I see it is java maintains the recursive call stack so as soon as an object is found there will be chances that the recursive method stack which is in the java stack run and overrides found value.

I see one option like set object at class level and use that object. Is there any better way to solve this problem?

**Not working solution**

```
public static void main(....){
    .....
    Resource root = service.getRoot();
    Resource searchResource =  new Resource();
    search(root, "child1_level2", searchResource);
    .....

}
public void search(Resource root, String search, Resource searchResource) {
        
        if (root.getSubResources() != null) {
            for (Resource subResource : root.getSubResources()) {
                if (StringUtils.equals(subResource.getName(), search)) {
                    searchResource = new Resource();
                    searchResource.setName(subResource.getName());
                    .......................
                    break;
                }else {
                    search(subResource, search, searchResource);
                }
                
            }

        } 
    }
```

**Working solution**

```
Resource searchResource =  new Resource();
public static void main(....){
    .....
    Resource root = service.getRoot();
    search(root, "child1_level2", searchResource);
    .....

}
public void search(Resource root, String search) {
        
        if (root.getSubResources() != null) {
            for (Resource subResource : root.getSubResources()) {
                if (StringUtils.equals(subResource.getName(), search)) {
                    searchResource = new Resource();
                    searchResource.setName(subResource.getName());
                    .......................
                    break;
                }else {
                    search(subResource, search);
                }
                
            }

        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd solution is correct. Just to be clear, the reason your 1st solution fails is that `searchResource.setName(subResource.getName());` is pointing at the variable declared in your method parameters, not the external variable like what you have in mind.

Simple alternative to bubble the answer up via method return:

```
public Resource search(Resource root, String search) {  
        if (root.getSubResources() != null) {
            for (Resource subResource : root.getSubResources()) {
                if (StringUtils.equals(subResource.getName(), search)) {
                    searchResource = new Resource();
                    searchResource.setName(subResource.getName());
                    return searchResource;
                }else {
                
                    Resource searchResult = search(subResource, search);
                    if (searchResult != null) {
                        return searchResult
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes correct but is there any good suggestion apart from second solution ?

Comment: An alternative would be to return the value you want in the method return, and just have it bubble back up to the original main method calling.

Comment: I tried to return as well but that again trap in same issue like ovveride value

Comment: You need to check if values returned are null or not and make sure to bubble the non-null result upwards the calling stack. I've provided a simple example in my answer

Comment: Thank you. Also I have one question like is there any good alternative of recursion?

Comment: Not in this case, no. If you want to check down to unspecified depth, recursion is the way